# Unique identifier for node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relational-database, database, nosql

I have two Neo4j databases. One is the old version and the other one is the new version. I would like to see which nodes are added to the new version.

For each node in the new version, I try to look if it exists in the old version.

How can I compare if it really is the same node on the other database? Is there a unique identifier in Neo4j nodes that I can use? In relational databases for instance, a row from a table has an ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare two things, you have to compare the two things based on your criteria for equality. If you change the *data* in a row of a relational database, comparison of the primary key does not guarantee equality. To make sure that two rows are the same, you have to check if the content of the row is the same (or if some other criterion for equality is true).

Nodes in neo4j do not have a unique identifier. They have an internal ID which is reused and should not be used to compare nodes. To make sure that every node from the old database is in the new one, you have to compare them one by one.

Comment: You are correct, for every node in the new database, I would have to loop through all the nodes in the old database to compare. But the question is how, since Neo4j is schema-less. I don't have a property which I can use to compare the values perhaps

Comment: @jmc Unless your nodes don't have labels at all, Neo4j is not _that_ schema-less. Just look for a node with the same labels and same properties (key + value) as the one in the new version?

Comment: @FrankPavageau still 2 nodes can have the same label. If also they don't have properties.

Comment: I'd argue you have an issue with your model, then, if the only thing discriminating 2 nodes is their Neo4j id, as it really should not be used outside of a Neo4j transaction. See e.g. the [release notes of 3.0.6](https://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-3-0-6/) which mention that the ids of relationships can change during the upgrade. Anyway, you could also compare the relationships of the nodes to see if the local graph has the same "shape". There's definitely no built-in solution here.

Answer (score 2):

If your data model had included an **explicit** unique ID property in every node, then it would be trivial to detect new nodes -- even if a node had property or relationship changes.

Comment: A property containing a globally unique value that you explicitly add to every node, as opposed to the native neo4j id that is automatically assigned to a node (but which can be assigned to another node once the node is deleted).

Comment: But if you change the properties of the node the explicit ID stays the same and you still have to check if the node is the same.

Comment: As written, the question is about detecting nodes added to the DB, and not about detecting node property changes.